# Why is it okay to store the state parameter for Authorization Code flow in a cookie?

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0, authorization, auth0, nonce

When implementing Authorization code flow in a regular web app, it's permitted to store the state parameter in cookies. See [here](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#NonceNotes) and [here] (https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/mitigate-csrf-attacks)

Why is storing the state (aka nonce) in a cookie an acceptable solution? For example if we do this in nodejs, the code will look something like this.

```
  app.use('/login', (_req, res) => {
    state = randomString(32)
    const authorizationEndpointUrl = new URL(`${activeConfig.authorization.domain}/authorize`);
    authorizationEndpointUrl.search = new URLSearchParams({
      audience: activeConfig.authorization.audience,
      response_type: 'code',
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8443/callback',
      client_id: activeConfig.authorization.clientId,
      scope: activeConfig.authorization.scope,
      state,
    }).toString();
    res.cookie('state', state, { httpOnly: true }); // cookie set here
    res.redirect(authorizationEndpointUrl.toString());
  });

  app.use('/callback', req => {
     // check that url state matches req.cookie.state???
  })
```

But if we do that, what stops an attacker from just setting the same "fake" state in the response url and cookie? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie you use for tracking the state should not be something that can be forged. The client should at a minimum sign it, so that no one but the client itself can generate it.
At that point an attacker would only be able to replay such a cookie if they happen to have access to the device right after the request was generated and before the legitimate response is returned, but not to forge an unprompted authorization response from an arbitrary device.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "replay such a cookie if they happen to have access to the device right after the request was generated and before the legitimate response is returned"

Even if I sign it, all this does is verify the cookie's authenticity. An attacker can still replay previous state strings, right? I'm not sure how preventing forgery safeguards from replay.

If we stored the nonce in something like Redis, then we are safe from playback since each nonce can only be used once since I can remove it from Redis after verification. How can I accomplish the same result with a cookie?

Comment: That use of the state isn't meant to prevent replays, only forgery. There are other measures for replay: for example, the client can delete the state tracking cookie as soon as it receives a response with matching state; every subsequent requests won't work because they won't be accompanied by a state tracking cookie. Or the client could maintain a cache of authorization codes it has seen and handled, rejecting any further use.
If you store the state value in reddis you are not tying the transaction to that particular user agent instance, which opens up different attack venues.

Comment: Really? Nonces are a common remedy for replay attacks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack#General_countermeasure_for_all_replay_attacks.

Plus auth0 even says that mismatched states indicate 
that "a response for an unsolicited request ."

"every subsequent requests won't work because they won't be accompanied by a state tracking cookie." Not sure what you mean here. Can't the attacker just include the an old nonce in the response url + cookie?

Sorry I don't mean to fight everything you're saying. I'm honestly still confused.

Comment: No worries :) “unsolicited request” is exactly what I mean by “forgery”. And if an attacker stole the cookie the attack you are handling is not forgery, it’s replay- and the countermeasure is to make the request single use: that is implemented with things like the cache I mentioned earlier, which can be tied on anything identifying the request (like the authz code or the state value itself).

Comment: "cache I mentioned earlier, which can be tied on anything identifying the request (like the authz code or the state value itself)."

Okay gotcha. So would it be impossible to enforce this single use with ONLY cookies? And is the OpenId specification knowingly okay with this because their goal is to prevent forgery and NOT replay. In other words storing the nonce in Redis would be better than cookie, but it doesn't matter from the perspective of the specification since the goal is to guard against forgery and NOT replay?

Comment: I have been discussing OAuth2 state so far, not OIDC nonce :) the OAuth WG in fact now recommends using PKCE rather than state as CSRF protection, freeing the state parameter to be used by the client to remember things between redirects. Reddis is  not necessarily a better solution, it just has different attack surface: as mentioned, the cookie is a way of tying to a particular browser instance which further locks down from where you accept requests (and a compromised channel, necessary for stealing cookies, would be a problem even after token issuance time).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208218/discussion-between-simon-and-vibronet).

Comment: By all means, tho I might not have a lot of bandwidth today

Answer (score 0):

According to the links you posted, the state param (nonce) should be added as a url parameter to the request.  oauth will validate against the url parameters and not the cookie.  So, having the nonce stored in the cookie shouldn't be a problem, it's not looking for the nonce in the cookie.  The attacker doesn't know the nonce to be able to craft the url parameters, I think is the point.  where you store the nonce doesn't matter really.

It is confusing they are calling this 'state'.  It's specifically for CSRF attacks.  Not to be confused with oauth tokens.  Those are already encrypted.

Comment: "The attacker doesn't know the nonce to be able to craft the url parameters, I think is the point. where you store the nonce doesn't matter really."

But if I store it in res.cookie, won't can't the attacker just look at the outgoing redirect request and see what the nonce is? I feel like I'm misunderstanding something very fundamental here.

Comment: Remember, this is for a cross-site attack.  The site that generated the forged request will not have access to the cookie data of the target domain.  The target domain will be looking for the nonce in the url, not the cookie that gets sent to it.

Comment: "The target domain will be looking for the nonce in the url, not the cookie that gets sent to it."

I thought I need to look in both to make sure they match?

"The site that generated the forged request will not have access to the cookie data of the target domain."

Okay. So are you saying that I shouldn't be worry about replay attacks because the attacker can't set the cookie?

Comment: This CSRF thing is a very specific attack.  Check the wikipedia on it:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery    If you're not allowing CORS on your api, I don't it's much to worry about.  I'm not sure what you mean by replay attacks.  No one should be able to see the cookie/token but the authorized client as long as you're using SSL.